# Showing inputs on sidebarpanel based on conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I want apply conditions in my shiny app so that, depending on an object `selected_source` Inputs are shown. The end result should create a table.

In the app I have 3 types of meals.

- If the `selected_type` is `NoMeal` then the menu option inputId = "vegan" and inputId = "NoVegan" wont be visible.
- If the `selected_type` is `Vegan` then only inputId = "vegan" will be visible.
- If the `selected_type` is `NonVegan` then only inputId = "nonvegan" will be visible.

To start with, here is a skeleton.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

type <- c("NoMeal", "Vegan", "NonVegan")
selected_type <- c("NoMeal")

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Menu"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "name",
              label = "Name",
              value = "Name"),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "vegan", 
                label = "Vegan",
                list(`Type` = list("Salad", "Noodles", "Soup"))),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "nonvegan", 
                label = "NonVegan",
                list(`Type` = list("Kebab", "Pizza", "BeefStake"))),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "selector", 
                label = "State", 
                choices = c("CA", "PA", "RA")),
    
    actionButton("button", "Enter")),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table")))))

server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(Name = character(),
                    Vegan = character(),
                    NonVegan = character(),
                    State = character()
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(Name = input$name,
                                     Vegan = input$vegan,
                                     NonVegan = input$nonvegan, 
                                     State = input$selector
                                     
    ))
    
    output$table <-renderTable({
      
      rv$df})
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to figure out how to apply conditions on the sidepanel. The final output table should look like this,

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the output outside the observer as

```
observeEvent(input$button, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(Name = input$name,
                                     Vegan = input$vegan,
                                     NonVegan = input$nonvegan, 
                                     State = input$selector
                                     
    ))
  })
  
  output$table <-renderTable({rv$df})
```